# Does a DNS server contain HTML objects?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, html

Does a DNS server contain HTML object files that are requested from an end user? I know that DNS servers house IP addresses that correlate to a canonical host name (because canonical host names are more readable than humans). When an end user searches for a website the client DNS on the application side takes the requested host name address and sends it to a server DNS which then returns an IP address and connects the end user's browser to the desired HTTP file.

My question is: does the HTML file come from a different server than the DNS server or does the DNS server also contain HTML object files?

Comment: when you type a url into a browser (or any other piece of software), the software asks the OS to resolve the target name into an IP address. The OS responds, and the software then opens a connection to the target IP address. they are two completely separate actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about two different services.

1. DNS
2. Web Server

There is no reason either has to be used in conjunction with, or on the same server as, the other. But, there is nothing preventing it either.

To answer your question, DNS servers do NOT host HTML objects (websites).  But the same physical server can also have a web server and serve web pages.